# Is there a cleaner way to use the write() function reliably?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, gcc

I read the `man` pages, and my understanding is that if `write()` fails and sets the `errno` to `EAGAIN` or `EINTR`, I may perform the `write()` again, so I came up with the following code:

```
  ret = 0;
  while(ret != count) {
    write_count = write(connFD, (char *)buf + ret,  count);
    while (write_count < 0) {
      switch(errno) {
        case EINTR:
        case EAGAIN:
          write_count = write(connFD, (char *)buf + ret,  count -ret);
          break;
        default:
          printf("\n The value of ret is : %d\n", ret);
          printf("\n The error number is : %d\n", errno);      
          ASSERT(0);
      }
    }
    ret += write_count;
  }
```

I am performing `read()` and `write()` on sockets and handling the `read()` similarly as above. I am using Linux, with `gcc` compiler.

Comment: Checking for EAGAIN would indicate you're using non-blocking sockets. I would maybe abstract this into a separate function that provides stats of how much was written and whether it failed badly.

Comment: @loan I am using blocking sockets. I didn't know that checking for EAGAIN needs to be done only if we are using non-blocking sockets.

Comment: That's why I mentioned it, just in case. I've only checked for EAGAIN on non-blocking sockets as that's how I understood it to work. If anyone knows that it occurs on blocking sockets, speak up.

Comment: @Ioan You are correct. It can't occur on blocking sockets.

Comment: You can use select() calls which would notify you as soon as the socket is ready to write.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a bit of a "don't repeat yourself" problem there - there's no need for two separate calls to `write`, nor for two nested loops.

My normal loop would look something like this:

```
for (int n = 0; n < count; ) {
    int ret = write(fd, (char *)buf + n, count - n);
    if (ret < 0) {
         if (errno == EINTR || errno == EAGAIN) continue; // try again
         perror("write");
         break;
    } else {
        n += ret;
    }
}

// if (n < count) here some error occurred
```

Comment: Okay, I see this is much more elegant. What is a "don't repeat yourself problem" ?

Comment: @AnkurVj it's repeating the same code unnecessarily - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself

Comment: DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) is a principle adopted in ['The Pragmatic Programmer'](http://www.amazon.com/The-Pragmatic-Programmer-Journeyman-Master/dp/020161622X) book.  It means avoid writing the same code twice.  Here, you are writing the `write` statement twice when once is sufficient.

Comment: It isn't appropriate to just burn the CPU in the case of `EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK.` The resolution of this state depends on the peer reading something. It won't just go away by itself. The correct procedure is to `select()` until the socket becomes writable.

Comment: I agree with @EJP. If you enabled the `SA_RESTART` flag, you wouldn't have `EINTR` and if you use a multiplexer, you know when it's appropriate to read.

Answer (score 3):

`EINTR` and `EAGAIN` handling should often be slightly different. `EAGAIN` is always some kind of transient error representing the state of the socket buffer (or perhaps, more precisely, that your operation may block).

Once you've hit an `EAGAIN` you'd likely want to sleep a bit or return control to an event loop (assuming you're using one).

With `EINTR` the situation is a bit different. If your application is receiving signals non-stop, then it may be an issue in your application or environment, and for that reason I tend to have some kind of internal `eintr_max` counter so I am not stuck in the theoretical situation where I just continue infinitely looping on `EINTR`.

Alnitak's answer (sufficient for most cases) should also be saving `errno` somewhere, as it may be clobbered by `perror()` (although it may have been omitted for brevity).

Comment: A portable application should check for both `EAGAIN` and `EWOULDBLOCK` as stated in `man` pages: "_POSIX.1-2001  allows either  error  to  be  returned  for this case, and does not require these constants to have the same value, so a portable application should check for both possibilities._" `EAGAIN` does not necessarily mean a blocking call for a `O_NONBLOCK` file descriptor and is implementation dependent.

Comment: @Barracuda Your last sentence is nonsense. It *never* means 'a blocking call'. It means that *if the call were executed in blocking mode,* it would have blocked. As it is, nothing happened and nothing blocked.

Comment: @EJP in `man 2 read` in `ERROR` section it's stated that: "_The file  descriptor `fd` refers to a socket and has been marked nonblocking (`O_NONBLOCK`), and the read would block._" does this mean _if a call were executed in blocking mode_, it would block? and what is _executing in blocking mode_ exactly?

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer to `poll` the descriptor in case of `EAGAIN` instead of just busy looping and burning up CPU for no good reason. This is kind of a "blocking wrapper" for a non-blocking `write` I use:

```
ssize_t written = 0;

while (written < to_write) {
    ssize_t result;
    if ((result = write(fd, buffer, to_write - written)) < 0) {
        if (errno == EAGAIN) {
            struct pollfd pfd = { .fd = fd, .events = POLLOUT };
            if (poll(&pfd, 1, -1) <= 0 && errno != EAGAIN) {
                break;
            }
            continue;
        }
        return written ? written : result;
    }
    written += result;
    buffer += result;
}
return written;
```

Note that I'm not actually checking the results of `poll` other than the return value; I figure the following `write` will fail if there is a permanent error on the descriptor.

You may wish to include `EINTR` as a retryable error as well by simply adding it to the conditions with `EAGAIN`, but I prefer it to actually interrupt I/O.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are cleaner ways to use `write()`: the class of write functions taking a `FILE*` as an argument. That is, most importantly, `fprintf()` and `fwrite()`. Internally, these library functions use the `write()` syscall to do their job, and they handle stuff like `EAGAIN` and `EINTR`.

If you only have a file descriptor, you can always wrap it into a `FILE*` by means of `fdopen()`, so you can use it with the functions above.

However, there is one pitfall: `FILE*` streams are usually buffered. This can be a problem if you are communicating with some other program and are waiting for its response. This may deadlock both programs even though there is no logical error, simply because `fprintf()` decided to defer the corresponding `write()` a bit. You can switch the buffering off, or `fflush()` output streams whenever you actually need the `write()` calls to be performed.