# how to write to a socket properly

Tags: c, linux, sockets

In the `man` pages of Linux about `write()` it's stated that in case of `EINTR` or `EAGAIN` `write()` will return `-1`. While performing a `read()` one may retry if such errors are encountered. What should be done in such situations when performing a `write()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, a way to handle such cases involves wrapping the `write()` call inside a function that checks the return value as well as the `errno` variable.

Cases like `EAGAIN` and `EINTR` indicate situations where the `write()` was unsuccessful because some signal interrupted it or `O_NONBLOCK` was set but the `write()` would block. This means you can retry the `write()` by probing the `errno` status.

**I'm not sure**, however, if it is guaranteed that `write()` will eventually succeed if you insist (and, of course, if you don't get any different `errno` status).

You could do something like

```
ssize_t insist_write(int fd, const void * buff, size_t cnt)
{
    ssize_t ret; 
    size_t original_cnt = cnt;
    while (cnt > 0)
    {
        ret = write(fd, buff, cnt);
        if (ret < 0) 
        {
            // EINTR for interrupted writes, EAGAIN - EWOULDBLOCK for file/socket
            // blocking case (see man page)
            if ((errno != EINTR) && (errno != EAGAIN) && (errno != EWOULDBLOCK))
               return ret;
            else 
               ret = 0;
        }
        // update buff and remaining bytes to write
        buff += ret;
        cnt -= ret;
    }
    return original_cnt;
}
```

I have also seen code where the above case is handled by doing

```
if (ret < 0) { return ret; }
```

instead of what I wrote, implying that such cases would be handled on a per-application basis (one such example is specifying a maximum number of `write()` attempts before returning `-1`).

Answer (score 1):

You can retry in the case of `EINTR.`

You can only get `EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK` if you're in non-blocking mode, and in those cases it isn't appropriate to just retry in a loop. You should `select()` until the socket becomes writable, and *then* retry. That can only happen when the peer reads something, which is why it isn't appropriate to burn CPU cycles at the sending end.

Answer (score -1):

It is true that you may wrap calls to `write()` by checking for `EINTR` or `EAGAIN`.  A simple loop to try the `write()` again in those cases is suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10340154/is-there-a-cleaner-way-to-use-the-c-write-function-reliably) question, and may work well:

Comment: The author wrote: "_I read the `man` pages, and my understanding is that if `write()` fails with error `EAGAIN` or `EINTR`, I should perform the `write()` again_" no, not necessarily. One may try again. It's implementation dependent and the `man` pages never said anything like that. His understanding and therefore the description of his question is wrong.